# Express.static() not working

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I have following server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var app = express();

//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
//both not working. I have tried multiple ways....

app.get("/",function (req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index/index.html")
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Webpack configs

```
module.exports = {
entry: './app/index/index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index'),
    publicPath: '/public/index',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'app/index/index.html'
    })
]};
```

Following directory structure:

```
      -public
        -index
          -index_bundle.js
```

I get the following error when I try to load my index_bundle js:

> GET http://localhost:3000/public/index/index_bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

I can't fix it and I found no solution on the web.

Comment: is there a folder named index in which index_bundle.js resides?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

to

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
```

You can use `DEBUG=* node <your-server-file>.js` to debug such express related issues.

A better more secure solution:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use("/public", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get("/",function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index/index.html")
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: That's not advisable for production code, since it will allow retrieval of _any_ file inside the project directory. Better use `app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`.

Comment: Express serving the statics is not advisable either. I'm just pointing out the issue with the presented code.

Comment: Sure, but in that case you should tell OP both: that your solution presents a security issue _and_ that they shouldn't use Express to serve static content in production.

Comment: @robertklep How about now?

Comment: Hey, why should I not use express to serve static files?

Comment: You probably want your application code (written in Nodejs) be freed of concerns (more importantly CPU power) related to serving static, which is better handled by something like Nginx. Serving static can be expensive on Node's single thread

Comment: Downvoted because `app.use("/public" ...)` makes no sense. Do crawlers look in /public for a robots.txt or manifests? No they do not.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
```

Note: Ensure that the name of the HTML file is `index.html` inside the public folder.